# Изменение цвета в верхней панели (colorPrimaryDark)

Tags: android, android-fragment

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]У меня есть фрагменты, и при нажатии на любой фрагмент в верхней части панели (там, где часы) должен измениться цвет. Как реализовать?

```
public class MainPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private final static int COUNT = 3;

private final static int HORIZONTAL = 0;
private final static int TWO_WAY = 1;
private final static int TWO_WAY1 = 2;

public MainPagerAdapter(final FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}
@Override
public Fragment getItem(final int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case TWO_WAY:
            return new HorizontalPagerFragment_bookmarks();
        case TWO_WAY1:
            return new HorizontalPagerFragment_exit();
        case HORIZONTAL:
            return new HorizontalPagerFragment();
        default:
    }
    return getItem(position);
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return COUNT;
}
```

}

public class HorizontalPagerFragment_bookmarks extends Fragment {

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable final ViewGroup container, @Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setStatusBarColor(R.color.colorAccent);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_horizontal1, container, false);
}


public void setStatusBarColor(int color) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        return;
    }
    Window window = getActivity().getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), color));
}
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1. Метод разместите в активности**

```
public void setStatusBarColor(int color) {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) { return; }
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, color));
}
```

**2. В `onCreate` активности повесьте слушатель на табы**

```
tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener(){
@Override
public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab){
    if(tab.getPosition() == 0){
        //красим статусбар цветом tab1 при клике на первый таб
        setStatusBarColor(R.color.tab1);
    }
    else{
        //и цветом tab2 при клике на второй таб
        setStatusBarColor(R.color.tab2);
    }
}
});
```

Comment: где мне это надо прописывать ?

Comment: В классе фрагмента. А вызывать метод в слушателе на фрагмент

Comment: можете написать полностью весь код ,с добавлением .Вверху мой код прилагается

Comment: Эм. Это вы должны сами сделать

Comment: смотрите код,вот так?

Comment: Метод верно размещен, а вот вызываете вы его в `onCreateView` тоесть при создании фрагмента. В вопросе аы написали что цвет статусбара должен меняться при клике на фрагмент. Значит вам надо поставить соушатель на корневой элемент фоагмента. Вы инфлэйтите разметку для фоагмента. `inflate` возвращает `view`, на который вам нужно установить `onClickListener`. А потом этот `view` возвращать по `return`

Comment: да все получилось,ноя наверное не так объяснил,мне нужно было как на фото вверху

Comment: То, что вы написали в вопросе - не то. Это не фрагменты а табы. Дополнить ответ? Метод не в фрагменте тогда должен быть а в активности

Comment: дополните тогда пожалуйста ответ .

Comment: Дополнил/изменил